# Refinement of an inequality that involves a mean built on the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, means, lambert-w

Deducing a similar derivation which is explained in the Wikipedia [*Stolarsky mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolarsky_mean#Derivation) I define for real numbers $1\leq x<y$ the mean $$M(x,y)=\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{x-y}{e^{W(x)}-e^{W(y)}}-1\right)\exp\left(\frac{x-y}{e^{W(x)}-e^{W(y)}}\right)\tag{1}$$
where $W(x)$ denotes the main/principal branch of the Lambert $W$ function. As usual the definition for $x=y$ will be $M(x,y)=x$.

I've used the function $f(x)=e^{W(x)}$ in the derivation, and calculating the inverse with the help of Wolfram Alpha online calculator.

My following question arises (I am inspired in this information) in a comment that added a professor in my own (now deleted post) MathOverflow **357442** with  title *A mean built on the principal branch of the Lambert*  $W$ *function: remarkable relationships with other means* (asked yesterday Apr 15 '20). I don't know if previous mean is in the literature, if you know it I would like to know about it, in this case please add a comment.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to deduce a bound $\text{bound}(x,y)$ satisfying for any real numbers $1\leq x<y$ that $$0<\text{bound}(x,y)< M(x,y)-M_{\text{lm}}(x,y),\tag{2}$$
>   where $M_{\text{lm}}(x,y)$ denotes the logarithmic mean. 
>   **Many thanks.**

If you need it you've the Wikipedia articles [*Lambert* $W$ *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and  [*Logarithmic mean.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean)

**Remarks as motivation.** I think that this exercise can be interesting because I can to learn this technique to get refinements for inequalities. If you are not able to do it for the segment of real numbers $x$ and $y$ with $1\leq x<y$ but you are able to find a more sharp inequality $(2)$ that holds for the segment $B<x<y$, for a fixed and positive real constant $B$ (I evoke a suitable choice of $B>1$), feel free to add your post as an answer. In recent past years in the literature are arising, in my opinion, articles that explore the importance of the function $f(x)=e^{W(x)}$, I wanted to create a mean inspired in some branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

### References:

[1] Kenneth B. Stolarsky, *Generalizations of the logarithmic mean*, Mathematics Magazine 48: pp. 87–92, (1975).

[2] The article *Lambert W-Function* from the online encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld and its related bibliography.

Comment: I hope that my question is interesting about how to get a bound for the difference  $M(x,y)-M_{\text{lm}}(x,y)$ as was asked $0<\text{bound}(x,y)< M(x,y)-M_{\text{lm}}(x,y)$, and that this inequality has a good mathematical content as problem. Feel free to add your feedback about the post.

Comment: In particular, I evoke **your feedback in comments** about my post/question, feel free if you can to advice to me about other inequalities for previous mean involving the Lambert $W$ function that can be interesting, or add your feedback in comments about different means related to maybe other branchs of the Lambert $W$ function that can be explored.

Comment: Many thanks for the upvotes and your attention in this post.